# Declaring a well colored digraph in coq

Tags: coq

I would like to declare a structure in coq which represents a digraph which is well colored. I declared a Register which is accepted by coq if I don't have a condition. However I tried many ways of writing the condition `wellColored` in coq without exit. Each time I get a new error message:

```
The condition wellColored is the following: 

for every pair of vertices $v1$, $v2$ and every edge $e$, if the source of $e$ is $v1$,
the target of $e$ is $v2$ and the color of $v1$ is $a$ then there is a color $b$ such that $b$ is different from $a$ and the color of $v2$ is $b$.
```

My attempt is written below. What are the mistakes in the condition `wellColored` and what is the correct definition?

```
Record dirgraph:={  
V:Set;  
E:Set;  
s:E->V; (* source function *)  
t:E->V; (* target function *)  
l:V->nat;  
wellColored: forall (v1:V) (v2:V) (e:E) (a:nat),   
In V v1 /\ In V v2 /\ In E e /\ s e v1 /\ t e v2 /\ l v1 a-> (exists b, b<>a /\ l v2 b)  
}.
```

For the moment I'm not interested in using packages with formalization of graphs. My main interest is to understand how to define structures and prove things about them. So I would like to define the graph precisely as it is above except with the correct condition.

Comment: Just for the record, the comment syntax in Coq doesn't have \ before `*`, i.e. `(* Toto *)` instead of `(\* Toto \*)`.

Comment: Thanks! I edited the question to remove the wrong comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your definition is that some conditions that you impose on `wellColored` do not need to be expressed, or simply cannot be expressed, in Coq's formalism:

1. I assume that by `In V v1` you mean that `v1` should be a member of `V`. Coq (as well as most type theories) is very different from usual set theory in this respect, because it doesn't make sense to assert that an object has some type *as a proposition* -- types in Coq (including things of type `Set`, like `V` in your definition) are *not* like sets in set theory. Instead, each object in the theory has its own type once and for all, and that type cannot change. When you write `forall (v1 : V), ...`, it is already assumed that `v1` is a member of `V`.

   If you want to say that some object of type `T` has some special property that not all objects of that type have (e.g., some number `n` is prime), you would express that with a *predicate* on that type (i.e., something of type `T -> Prop`), and *not* as a "subset" of `T`, as you would do in set theory.
2. You defined `s`, `t` and `l` as functions of one argument, but used them as two-argument functions, as in `s e v1`. I suppose you wanted to say something like `v1 = s e`, i.e. `v1` is the source of edge `e`. However, there's no need to say that: `s e` is an expression of type `V` like any other, and can be used directly, with no need to declare additional variables (see below). Likewise, you don't need to say that there exists some color `b` that is different from `a`: you can just refer to the color of that node directly.

Here's a version of your type that avoids those problems:

```
Record dirgraph:={
  V:Set;
  E:Set;
  s:E->V; (* source function *)
  t:E->V; (* target function *)
  color: V->nat;
  wellColored:
    forall e : E, color (s e) <> color (t e)
}.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still having some difficulties to leave set theory :) But your answer was very clarifying.