# Coq contradiction in hypotheses

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

In Coq I have two hypotheses `H` and `H0`, that contradict each other. Problem is, they only contradict each other for some specializations and at this moment of the proof the context is not that specialized.

At this moment my proof context looks like this:

```
color : Vertex -> bool 
v : V_set 
a : A_set 
x0, x1 : Vertex 
H : v x0 -> v x1 -> a (A_ends x0 x1) \/ a (A_ends x1 x0) -> color x0 <> color x1 
H0 : v x0 -> v x1 -> a (A_ends x0 x1) \/ a (A_ends x1 x0) -> color x0 = color x1
______________________________________ 
False
```

As this proof is about graphs (`v` = set of vertices, `a` = set of arcs, `color` = color of a vertex), I could easily show the contradiction in natural language: suppose some graph contains vertices `x0` and `x1` (and they are neighbouring), `x0` and `x1` cannot have the same and different color at the same time. Therefore `H` and `H0` cannot both be true and therefore the goal is implied by the current context.

How should I go about this in Coq, without generating `v x0`, `v x1` and `a (A_ends x0 x1) \/ a (A_ends x1 x0)` as new subgoals all the time? The tricky part is the: "suppose some graph exists with `v` and `a` of such and such forms".

So far I tried `auto, eauto, trivial, intuition, apply H in H0, contradiction H, omega`.

Comment: I am afraid that you'll have to generate the missing proof obligations, or else prove why they are not needed. Coq is about _proof verification_ so indeed you cannot expect informal reasoning to keep working here. It is hard to know without knowing more, however the key likely is in the path you followed to arrive to that goal. You write down "suppose", so that supposition, should appear previously somewhere, right?

Comment: The first step to automating a proof is to have a manual proof. So, ignoring for now the annoyance of generating the subgoals, how do you prove `v x0`, `v x1` and `a ... \/ a ...`?

Comment: I guess I need something like a _specialization_ for `v` and `a`, which have the form needed. Informally this should again be fine, "when these hypotheses hold in general, then they have to hold for this particular instance". But Coq doesn't allow such a specialization here, as `v` and `a` are used in other Hypotheses.

Comment: I'm afraid without a complete, runnable example we won't be able to help here.

Comment: After changing my lemma using something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26893423/declaring-a-well-colored-digraph-in-coq), I could solve the lemma. Then I didn't have to prove `v x0` and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you need to make sure that your context matches your informal reasoning.  You say:

> suppose some graph contains vertices `x0` and `x1` (and they are neighbouring), `x0` and `x1` cannot have the same and different color at the same time.

However, this is not what your context says.  Your context says "suppose you have a graph and two vertices `x0` and `x1` (which may or may not be in the vertex set of that graph).  If it happens that `x0` and `x1` in particular are in the vertex set of that graph, and are neighboring, then they must have different colors (this is `H0`).  However, we already have that in this case, `x0` and `x1` have the same color (this is `H1`)."  The obvious conclusion to draw is not absurdity, but simply that these `x0` and `x1` are not on the graph, or are not neighboring.  For concreteness, the graph might be empty, or have only one vertex and no edges.

I would suggest stepping through the proof tactic by tactic, translating each context and goal back into natural language, and looking for the point at which you go from a true theorem to a false one.